# Import Google fonts in react native while using Switch Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-fonts

So I am writing an application in which I am using the Switch Navigator for react native along with React Expo. All import instructions advise to import the fonts in App.js and use it on

```
export default function App() {...}
```

Problem is that by using the Switch Navigator I now have

```
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Loading: LoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Loading"
    }
  )
)
```

and I can't find a way to apply the instruction I have found here for example:
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts/
since my default export from App.js uses a Switch Navigator function. Do I have to separately import the fonts on every Screen or maybe switch to a custom font load approach since I am using the Switch Navigator like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way to do this, in case someone stumbles upon it.

So I had to refactor the export default function like this:

```
const RootApp = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Loading: LoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Loading"
    }
  )
)

export default function App() {

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Lobster_400Regular,
  });


    if (!fontsLoaded) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
    // from the custom App we return the component we assigned to RootApp.
    return <RootApp />;
}
```